# rpm is installed / rpm is not installed issue

Tags: rpm, oracle-linux

I've run into a bit of an issue with rpm on an Oracle Linux 6.5 box.

I installed an RPM, and it appears to have installed successfully.  However, now I am trying to remove it, but rpm says it's already installed.  I am trying to uninstall it by package name, not the full *.rpm name.  Ex:

```
[root@server06 ~]# rpm -ivh package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm

Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package custom-linux-9026-10.0.0-BUILD116.noarch is already installed

[root@server06 ~]# rpm -ql package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm
package package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm is not installed

[root@server06 ~]# rpm -q package-10.0.0B116
package package-10.0.0B116 is not installed

[root@server06 ~]# rpm -e package-10.0.0B116
error: package package-10.0.0B116 is not installed
```

So the system won't let me install it again because it thinks it's already there, but won't let me uninstall it because it thinks it's not there.

`rpm -qa |grep -i package` returns nothing.

`rpm --rebuilddb` doesn't help either.

Comment: My guess is that it's not always obvious what the *package name*, the *package version*, and what the *package release* are when you see the combined string. I think either only the package name (when there only exists one such package), or the complete package_name-version-release string is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Notice the line:

```
package custom-linux-9026-10.0.0-BUILD116.noarch is already installed
```

So despite the filename of package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm the package (in rpm header) is likely named custom-linux-9026-10.0.0-BUILD116. So you must call

```
rpm -e custom-linux-9026-10.0.0-BUILD116
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the original rpm file, extract the package name from it with `-qp` and the filename, eg

```
$ rpm -qp ~/myrpm-1.0-05077.i586.rpm
myrpm-1.0-05077.i586
```

and try using that in the rpm erase, as the filename might not match the package name.

Comment: This! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`rpm -aq | grep -i package.rpm` if still not getting the output, then run `updatedb` command and try again

`i` will if ignore case sensitive

If you want to remove the `rpm` please give the full package name.

`rpm -e package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm`

Comment: I already tried those:

[root@server06 ~]# updatedb


[root@server06 ~]# rpm -qa |grep package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm


[root@server06 ~]#


[root@server06 ~]# rpm -e package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm
error: package package-10.0.0B116-02202013-x64.rpm is not installed
 

[root@server06 ~]# rpm -e package-10.0.0B
error: package package-10.0.0B is not installed

Answer (score 0):

The real problem seems to be that the package you are trying to remove wasn't actually installed:

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package custom-linux-9026-10.0.0-BUILD116.noarch is already installed
```

And the package name seems to be `custom-linux-9026-10.0.0-BUILD116.noarch`.