# How query custom installed rpm package

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, rpm

How query custom installed rpm package

Generally if i need to query rpm based package I use following commands

```
rpm -qi package

rpm -ql package        # to get installed binaries of package

rpm -qf path to binary # to get related package name of the path
```

All above mentioned commands work very well with all the installed packages, but problem raised when I have installed package in custom location using following commands

```
rpm –prefix=/opt -ivh package

rpm -relocate=/opt  -ivh package
```

So when I used above mentioned commands package got installed properly but I was not able to use following rpm query commands

```
rpm -qi package

rpm -ql package       # to get installed binaries of package

rpm -qf path to binary # to get related package name of the path
```

Is there a way I can query custom installed rpm package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your comments, you may want to try:

```
rpm -qi --root=/opt atop
```

When you use the `--installroot` flag for `yum`, it uses or creates a new `rpm` database in that location.  When you run `rpm` without the `--root` flag it will look at the default `rpm` database in `/var/lib/rpm` which does not have any knowledge of your custom package install.

Comment: worked for me @GracefulRestart

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282769/rpm-is-installed-rpm-is-not-installed-issue) looks to be similar to yours. If you have rpm file please check

```
rpm -qp /path/to/your/package.rpm
```

to see if the package has another name than rpm file.

Comment: thanks for quick response

Let me elaborate my question

Comment: thanks for quick response

Let me elaborate my question

Case 1 : yum install atop 

[root@host ~]# rpm -qi atop
Name        : atop                         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.27                              Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 2.el6                         Build Date: Thu 16 Jan 2014


Case 2 :

yum install atop --installroot=/opt

[root@cl14470 ~]# rpm -qi atop
package atop is not installed
In case 2 rpm related query commands are not working, I am looking for a way to query custom installed rpm

Comment: Looks like your package is not installed in fact. `Relocations: (not relocatable)` states that the package cannot be relocated using `--prefix`. You have to receive an error on output when run `yum install atop --installroot=/opt`.